# T SQL Conditional join

Tags: t-sql, left-join

forgive my language, English is not my mother tongue.

The following scenario exists:

An object, let's call it an apartment for simplicity, can (but does not have to) refer to a parent object of the same type that we now call house.

The apartment may have an address (other table), if not the address of the house is relevant.

For this I try to build a join, which returns either the address of the apartment (if available), or the address of the house.

My previous approach:

```
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.stelle_adressen AS ADR_Default ON 
        (ADR_Default.stelle_id = stelle.stelle_id 
         AND ADR_Default.adress_typ_id = 1 
         AND ADR_Default.aktiv = 1)
        OR
        (ADR_Default.stelle_id = stelle.referenz_id 
         AND ADR_Default.adress_typ_id = 1 
         AND ADR_Default.aktiv = 1)
```

Also works, just not as needed, because if a housing address is present, also the join to the house address is formed, and therefore 2 lines are delivered as a result.

Any advice?

Simplified Query:

```
SELECT        
    stelle.stelle_id, 
    ADR_DOBJ.adr_objekt_id, 
    ADR_STR.strasse, 
    ADR_STR.plz, 
    ADR_STR.ort, 
    ADR_DOBJ.hausnummer, 
    ADR_Default.aktiv
FROM            
    stelle 
    INNER JOIN
    stelle_adressen AS ADR_Default ON  
    (ADR_Default.stelle_id = stelle.stelle_id AND ADR_Default.adress_typ_id = 1 AND ADR_Default.aktiv = 1) 
    OR 
    (ADR_Default.stelle_id = stelle.referenz_id AND ADR_Default.adress_typ_id = 1 AND ADR_Default.aktiv = 1) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    adr_objekt AS ADR_DOBJ ON ADR_DOBJ.adr_objekt_id = ADR_Default.adr_objekt_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    adr_objekt_strassen AS ADR_STR ON ADR_STR.strasse_id = ADR_DOBJ.strasse_id
WHERE stelle.stelle_id = 2
```

Result:

```
stelle_id   adr_objekt_id   strasse plz ort hausnummer  aktiv
2   8   Walterhöferstraße   14165   Berlin  11  1
2   1   Gustav-Adolf-Straße 13086   Berlin  106a    1
```

Expected Result:

```
stelle_id   adr_objekt_id   strasse plz ort hausnummer  aktiv
2   8   Walterhöferstraße   14165   Berlin  11  1
```

The query return 2 rows, one with own adress, one with adress of refered object adress (which should only be returned if no own adress is available)

Comment: Could you also show all the query and your output with duplicates? And the result which you want to expect.

Comment: @Leran2002 added requested additional information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As variant you can try to use `TOP 1` with `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT TOP 1
    stelle.stelle_id, 
    ADR_DOBJ.adr_objekt_id, 
    ADR_STR.strasse, 
    ADR_STR.plz, 
    ADR_STR.ort, 
    ADR_DOBJ.hausnummer, 
    ADR_Default.aktiv
FROM stelle 
JOIN stelle_adressen AS ADR_Default ON
      ADR_Default.adress_typ_id = 1 AND ADR_Default.aktiv = 1
  AND (ADR_Default.stelle_id = stelle.stelle_id OR ADR_Default.stelle_id = stelle.referenz_id) 
LEFT JOIN
    adr_objekt AS ADR_DOBJ ON ADR_DOBJ.adr_objekt_id = ADR_Default.adr_objekt_id 
LEFT JOIN
    adr_objekt_strassen AS ADR_STR ON ADR_STR.strasse_id = ADR_DOBJ.strasse_id
WHERE stelle.stelle_id = 2
ORDER BY IIF(ADR_Default.stelle_id = stelle.referenz_id,2,1)
```

The priority of `stelle.stelle_id` is 1, and `stelle.referenz_id` is 2.

Do you always want to get only one row?
Do the condition `WHERE stelle.stelle_id = 2` use always?

If you want to get addresses for several `stelle_id` you can try the following

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (
    SELECT
        stelle.stelle_id, 
        ADR_DOBJ.adr_objekt_id, 
        ADR_STR.strasse, 
        ADR_STR.plz, 
        ADR_STR.ort, 
        ADR_DOBJ.hausnummer, 
        ADR_Default.aktiv,
        ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY stelle.stelle_id ORDER BY IIF(ADR_Default.stelle_id = stelle.referenz_id,2,1)) N
    FROM stelle 
    JOIN stelle_adressen AS ADR_Default ON
          ADR_Default.adress_typ_id = 1 AND ADR_Default.aktiv = 1
      AND (ADR_Default.stelle_id = stelle.stelle_id OR ADR_Default.stelle_id = stelle.referenz_id) 
    LEFT JOIN
        adr_objekt AS ADR_DOBJ ON ADR_DOBJ.adr_objekt_id = ADR_Default.adr_objekt_id 
    LEFT JOIN
        adr_objekt_strassen AS ADR_STR ON ADR_STR.strasse_id = ADR_DOBJ.strasse_id
    --WHERE stelle.stelle_id = 2
  ) q
WHERE N=1
```

I've commented the condition `WHERE stelle.stelle_id = 2` here.

PS. I think you also can use condition `AND ADR_Default.stelle_id IN(stelle.stelle_id,stelle.referenz_id)` instead `AND (ADR_Default.stelle_id = stelle.stelle_id OR ADR_Default.stelle_id = stelle.referenz_id)`.

Comment: I've modified your answer because IIF is not working on SQL-Server 2008 (used CASE WHEN instead of IIF). Big thanks for your hints, solved my question :)

Comment: I'm very glad that I could help you. ) Good luck!